# Fatal error: Hmm - depth calc wrong, hit negatives, in silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Fatal error: Hmm - depth calc wrong, hit negatives, in silverstripe after doing a dev/build, it also says /htdocs/framework/core/manifest/ConfigStaticManifest.php on line 278?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for program structure whenever you see this kind of error in Silverstripe, make sure it's a valid PHP program, for example make sure all parenthesis and curly braces are properly closed.

Comment: I got this too on a dev/build and found out that it was because there was a extra closing curly bracket } which was ending a function before the end. As suggested above, double-check your syntax is valid.